# Assign a parent page to all WordPress posts

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I am building the actual Website as well as the blog into a single WordPress theme. I've got everything setup, there is a blog page (www.mysite.com/blog/) which is set as the "Posts Page" and all the posts are displayed on this page as excerpts.

However, each post has the following URL: www.mysite.com/post1/, I need all post to have the blog page as their parent, so that their URLs will change to: www.mysite.com/blog/post1/.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance
Willem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily by changing your permalink structure. Just include /blog/ at the start of your custom structure.

It seems to only affect posts and not pages, which is what you want.

Comment: Well, now I feel quite silly. I just assumed that would also affect pages. Thanks for the info.

Kind Regards
Willem

Comment: Actually I assumed the same thing, but tested it anyway and was surprised!